# Ranger Coprocessor error in HBase (Vanilla hadoop)

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-ranger

Setting up the ranger on the vanilla version of Hadoop
Ranger 2.1
hdfs plugin & hive are working fine,
but I can't solve the error with hbase plugin

I ran into an error when enabling the ranger plugin

```
September 15, 09: 04:06 dn01 hbase[504922]: 2021-09-15 09:04:06,200 ERROR [dn01:60000.activeMasterManager] of the coprocessor.Coprocessor Host: Coprocessor org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.rangerauthorizationprocessor threw java. lang. NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/coprocessor/regionprocessor

FATAL [dn01:60000.activeMasterManager] master.HMaster: The coprocessor org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor threw java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/coprocessor/RegionCoprocessor
```

In hbase-site.xml when the plugin is enabled, it adds

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.security.authorization</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.coprocessor.master.classes</name>
  <value>org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
  <value>org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor</value>
</property>
```

when enabled, the plugin copies its libraries to the local path where hbase is installed or creates symbolic links

Do you have any ideas how to fix this error?

Ranger 2.1

HBase 1.4.12

Maybe there is a version conflict?

Thanks!

Comment: Definitely looks like a version error. Why aren't you using Hbase 2.x?

Comment: Developers are not ready to update the version... Ll have to to put the second ranger in docker